# How to find all linear columns dependency in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find the index of all linear columns in matrix. The output is a vector in which gives 1 for independent columns and -1 for all linear dependency columns. For example, I have a matrix A that is

```
A =

     1     0     0     0     0     1   1
     1     0     0     1     0     1   1
     1     1     1     0     1     1   1
     1     1     1     0     1     1   0
```

We can see that column dependency are 1,2,3,5,6. Hence my expected result are

```
output=[-1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1];
```

And the independent matrix remains

A =

```
           0     1
           1     1
           0     1
           0     0
```

How to implement it by matlab ?
How about with linear rows?

Comment: What if we swap col2 and col4 in the input, what would be the output then?

Comment: Sorry, I give the mistake example of column 4. Let check again

Comment: Not sure I got the definition of "dependency" right here.

Comment: I think we can see that only col4 is linear dependency with all other col. So it will return 1 otherwise, other columns linear together (1,6) and( 2,3,5)

Comment: This is one example http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49984-how-to-remove-dependent-rows-in-a-matrix

Comment: I guess you want to keep at least one of the linearly dependent columns, right?

Comment: No. I want to keep all independent columns. And remove all dependent columns.

Comment: OK, so only unique columns? Note that this operation will reduce rank of the matrix

Comment: yes, sir. And set output -1 for linear column as my question

Comment: What is the output of `[1 1 0; 1 0 1]`. And why do you want this, normally independant columns are sought after to do things like regression, but here you will definitely want to keep 1 of the dependant columns as is given by `rref`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I must remove it because in linear equation Ax=b, if two cols are dependent, we can not found these element in this col. For example x1+x2+x3=0;x1+x2=1;x1+x2+x3=0;So we only find x3,while x1 and x2 will not find.

Comment: You will not find the unique solution for those values, but you can still find a solution. Also, I assume you are aware of `X = linsolve(A,B)`

Comment: It is not correct answer. Note that x is binary={0,1}. 1 xor 1 similar 1+1=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this -

```
out = ones(1,size(A,2))
out(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(A,[1 3 2])),1),2)>=2)=-1
```

So, basically for each column, it finds if there are any other matching columns and if there are, it identifies that as a "dependent" (from what I could gather as the definition for this problem) column.

Output -

```
out =
    -1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1     1
```

---

For finding "dependency" across rows, use this -

```
out = ones(1,size(A,1))
out(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(A,[3 2 1])),2),1)>=2)=-1
```

Comment: How to make the output matrix A that only maintains independent column

Comment: How about with row independent,sir? Very nice

Comment: @user3051460 Use `A(:,out==1)`.

Comment: Yes. I got it. Please help me the rows independent

Comment: @user3051460 Quick fix on that, transpose A and use this code?

Comment: Thank Divakar, However, let check with this case where col4 will depent col1 and 2.(col4=col1-col2) . I want to delete all 1,2,4 A =

     [1     0     0     1     0     1;
     1     0     0     1     1     0;
     1     1     1     0     0     1;
     1     1     0     0     1     1]

Comment: I don't think this checks all possible linear dependencies. Check `A = repmat(eye(2),2)` It only has 2 linear independant columns (as shown by the alternate answer) but I don't get this as output.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Well for that input, all columns are dependent according to the way I think OP meant to define "dependency", so it has to output all `-1s` which it does, so it looks fine to me.

Comment: @user3051460 Does A contain only ones and zeros?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin In the other answer, it outputs just the unique rows, which isn't exactly right, as that way you would have the first column of A into the output too, which isn't what OP wants (if you read the expected output in the question). Hope that makes more sense?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin And as for `A = repmat(eye(2),2)` case, col1 depends on col3 and col2 on col4, according to the way OP is defining "dependency". Thus, there are no independent cols, as such, out must be all `-1s`, which is what you would get with this solution, not if you go with `unique` rows based solution. That's really the thing here.

Comment: @Divakar After your comment on the answer below I did not think to check whether it would be correct (currently it does not match what the asker asks, but perhaps it matches what he really needs). I guess you are right that the asker uses an unusual definition and have removed my downvote.

Comment: @Thanks! But yeah that definition is still pretty shaky as OP is asking to modify it further, let's see how it goes there.

Comment: @Divakar: A is binary matrix. So, It only has 1 and 0

Comment: @user3051460 For that new requirement, the solutions have to  be changed a lot and I think it would be best to post a new question with that requirement being stated clearly in it.

Comment: Let see it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249859/how-to-resolve-linear-equation-ax-b-using-gaussian-elimination

Comment: @Divakar Removed my answer as indeed it doesn't answer the question